# microseconds delays and spinlock in Linux driver context

Tags: linux, driver, mutex, spinlock

I have a general question regarding spinlock and delays in the driver context. I have a Linux driver that read and write in the gpio. The reading and writing operation are done in a single pin and it is totally timing based (**HDQ protocol**). The original driver is implemented using udelay() calls and the worst scenario is about **500 us**. 
The driver does not implement anything as interruption, just regular reading and writings in a specific GPIO using the regular **gpio_get_value()** and **gpio_set_value()**.
Between these delays, the driver contains spinlocks. How safe is this ? I am a little concerned with these delays enclosed by spinlocks.

Answer (score 2):

`udelay` is safe to use in atomic sections (i.e. within spinlocks or interrupts). Look at [the kernel timers howto](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/timers-howto.txt) for all the details.

You could be concerned about performance, because `udelay` is busy-waiting. However, it would be difficult to be sure of meeting the timing requirements when schedulable sleeps are used, because they are not precise. On *most* processors, `usleep` should be accurate enough, but it's less certain than `udelay`. And in addition, you can't hold the spinlock when calling `usleep` so a different synchronisation mechanism has to be used.